# How to edit apache superset's report email

Tags: docker, apache-superset

I am running [apache superset 2.0.0-dev](https://github.com/apache/superset). Everything works great. I just want to change the text that comes inside the report emails. Here is a photo of the current email it sends (this is just some example dashboard that superset provides):
[image]
The text in the hyperlink that I circle is what I want to change. I have already gone through a lot of the code looking for that string "Explore in Superset". As well as searched through the [repo on github](https://github.com/apache/superset/search?q=%22Explore%20in%20Superset%22&type=code)

I changed every instance I can find of the string "Explore in Superset" to the text I want, but none have an effect on the email that is sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'd make the change in [`email.py`](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/ce145c676cbcd3921fce4546a9ea586d0d72fa82/superset/reports/notifications/email.py#L131), changing the value of the `call_to_action` variable.

This doesn't appear to be a user-configurable setting.  That is, if you were deploying using Docker containers, you would have to build your own image of Superset that contains this change, then run that image.

Comment: I understand. Do you have any references as to how I can do that? I am new to docker and don't have a clue on how a modification like that would look like.

Comment: I believe you'd clone the Github repository, checkout the commit tagged as 2.0.0, and make the change to the source code.  Then you'd build and deploy the image, that part isn't specific to Superset so read up on Docker generally there.  This likely will be many hours of learning and work.  That could be worthwhile if there are other customizations you would like to make or you want to learn about Docker, but otherwise it's a big lift for one cosmetic change.

Comment: The other long-term option is to start a Github discussion on the Superset repo asking for this text to be customizable and explaining your use case.  Then maybe someone can change the software so that you can customize this text, either on a report-by-report basis or by putting a new string in `config.py`.

Comment: thank you. I do need to learn more about docker, so this would be a good way to do so.